# Display json result into a list view

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am trying to return a simple message using an api call. 
I am trying to work out how to return and display the result into a list view.

i can display the message view a txtview or the console, but not sure how to turn this into displaying in the list view.

```
void client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
            List<Message> message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(json);

            //display the retrieved msg in the console output
            //Console.WriteLine(message[1].message + " is the message");

            //display the msg in a text view at top of page
            //txt.Text = message[1].message;




        }
```

Comment: You might want to set `ListView.Items` property to populate your list view. Can you please the definition of `Message` class?

Comment: public class Message
 {
  public string message { get; set; }
 }
}

Comment: so would I use an adapter say msgListview.Adapter = message[1].message;

or how do you mean set the ListView.items..?

Comment: I've produced an answer assuming you are working on a list view control in windows forms. Please let me know if you face any problem in leveraging it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your definition of your `Message` class you can do something like this to bind all the messages to your list view. You will have to import `using System.Linq;` at the top of  your cs file.

```
void client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
    //List<Message> message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(json);
    //mock list of messages which you will get after deserializing the json above
    List<Message> message = new List<Message> { new Message { message = "message1" }, new Message { message = "message2" }, new Message { message = "message3" } };

    var allMessages = message.Select(x => x.message);

    foreach (var messageItem in allMessages)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(messageItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up being able to retrieve the messages using this:

Comment: //get the list view create a string to store and add to the list view based on the json return
   msgListview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.msgListView);
   Msgs = new List<string>();
   Msgs.Add(message[1].message);
   Msgs.Add(message[0].message);

   ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Msgs);

   msgListview.Adapter = adapter;

Comment: Would you be able to help me turn that into a loop so that I dont have to enter in the number of each message to return??

Comment: Sure I would want to help but I'm finding it really difficult to understand the code that you have posted in your comment. It will be really easy to understand if you can put your code into the post itself and then explain as to what more you want to achieve.